# RxJava Observable outside Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, rx-java

I'll be replacing all of my AsyncTasks codes with RxJava Observable. Currently, all tasks are outside the fragment. Do I need to unsubscribe? When and Where?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Specify how you will use your Observable. You absolutely should unsubscribe, If your subscriber will depend on activity/fragment lifecycle and hold references to activity/fragment/view

Comment: I have separate class with CRUD (create, retrieve..) with AsyncTask each method. Inside OnPostExecute, I have listener just to pass the query data to the fragment. Where can I unsubscribe since I'll just replace the AsyncTask with an Observable inside my separate class?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a public method that lets you access your `Observable`. After you `subscribe()`, you receive a `Subscription` object.

You can dispose the subscription whenever you like, for instance:

- In `Activity.onDestroy()`, if you want to bind it to the `Activity` lifecycle
- You can bind it to an `OnClickListener`, if you want the user to be able to interrupt a network request.

These two are just two examples. If you want something more Activity Lifecycle oriented, give a look at [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let say, If I'm having a separate class also to subscribe and get the data from onCompleted then I'll just pass the string value to the fragment. Where can I unsubscribe since subscribe (Observable) is outside the fragment?

Comment: The moment you reach `onCompleted()` the `Subscription` is disposed. When you get the new data in the `onNext(T)`, how do you pass it to the Fragment? If you are working with a `Subject` and with an on-going `Subscription`, you can bind your `Fragment` lifecycle to some method of your separate class that dispose all the still active subscriptions.